# Persist login/Authentication info on Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

What is the best way to persist a users info in an android app?  I have a login screen that uses a web service to authenticate the user and return basic user info.

I don't care about saving the username/password, but I do need things like a couple of integer ID fields (patientID and personID) and a first and last name.

I don't want the user to have to login every time they load the app.  Someone suggested I use SQL lite to store the info, is this the best way or is there a more light weight solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)
refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) also

Comment: ...unless you actually care about security, in which case the documentation recommends [`AccountManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the answers and comments to this question: [Android: Storing username and password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925486/android-storing-username-and-password/)