# How to secure passwords on mobile

Tags: android, security, encryption

I am trying to secure my passwords and website information.
Looking something equivalent to TrueCrypt.

Can Some one help me on the same.

Regards,
Vignesh

Comment: Check this .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359399/storing-a-password

Comment: Truecrypt was succeeded by veracrypt. Nonetheless, this is not really an Android question.

Answer (score 0):

- Use MD5 or UTF8 kind of strategies before storing and retriving. And for better idea on these kindly look into below..

[For Sample stuff - 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934331/android-how-to-encrypt-a-string)

[For Sample stuff - 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934331/android-how-to-encrypt-a-string/19589939#19589939)

Comment: As MD5 is widly used and there are a lot of Rainbowtables out there in which you can pass the MD5 hash and get the password in clear text, you should also consider adding a lot of salt (insert some random characters based on you own algoithm so you can redo it) and mix it with serveral other hashing alogrithms for increasing security

Comment: I too agree with this concern. And it was always more preferable to have one's own algorithm for better security.. And these samples might give better idea to start with..