# Login and Password Activity

Tags: android

How to make a login and password for an Application activity?
So you can not enter until shalt bring data.

Comment: This is not a real question. Could you please rephrase it and tell us what exactly you want to achieve, what you tried and what you expect?

Comment: here is the code to get u started.. has everything welcome screen & login ..stores data in sharedpref http://androidsamples.blogspot.in/2009/06/how-to-use-http-connection-saxparser.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into the Authenticator Activity

[AuthenticatorActivty](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/src/com/example/android/samplesync/authenticator/AuthenticatorActivity.html)

You can also check out this other post on SO if you are interested in storing Usernames and passwords.

[SO Post to store Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925486/android-storing-username-and-password)

If you clear up your question I will be more than happy to edit my answer to help ya out more.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use SQL. Try that! Or i depends if you want to have information sotred on local or Internet.