# Maintaining Sessions

Tags: php, android, session

I am developing an API based Android application in which user can make his/her account. User can log in and out. The web services are through PHP. So my question is whether it would be better to maintain session in PHP or in Android(using SharedPreferences).

Comment: `shared preferences` in case of android.

Answer (score 0):

For Android API implementation my suggestion will be referring **Android Preference** is good, rather than php sessions.

Comment: please take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925486/android-storing-username-and-password)