# How variables are stored after compilation?

Tags: java, compilation

I have in my program (written in Java) a variable:

```
String myPassword
```

After compiling the code with Android Studio, I get an an android application and I would like to let other people to use it.

But I am scared: is it possible for the users to get the variable value (password) from the application?

Let's say that the password value is *"myPass"*. Its binary is:

`01101101 01111001 01010000 01100001 01110011 01110011`

Will the application binary contain this sequence in it?

Comment: Yes, its possible, either by examining the compiled binary or by looking for it in memory at runtime.  Don't store sensitive information in anything publicly accessible.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response @AlexK. So what should I do?

Comment: You can't distribute an application containing a password and keep the password secure. It's not possible. People can decompile your code; or they can just watch what the application is doing and wait for it to use the password.

Comment: You need to think up an authentication scheme that does not involve hardcoding passwords in your application, E.g. [Android: Storing username and password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925486/android-storing-username-and-password)

Comment: Also useful info about passwords in Java: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords

Answer (score 2):

If you decompile your classes with `javap -c -p -constants` for example you would see those Strings:

```
public class DeleteMe {

   private static final String test = "def";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String test = "abc";
   }
}
```

would yield(the important two lines):

```
private static final java.lang.String test = "def";
ldc           #2                  // String abc
```

Otherwise, storing passwords inside your app is really bad, usually people employ some sort of database where passwords are kept for example.

Also [the must read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords) about `String` and `char[]` for passwords.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Let's say I want to connect to the database that contains the table that contains the password. I will have to connect to the database with credentials:

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("url", "user", "passwd");

So if I do that, are the "user" string and "passwd" string protected?

Comment: @NewWorker to be honest, I am not an android dev, so I have no idea what are the best practices for android, but I assume there are ways to asymmetrically encrypt passwords, like Android keystore (this is what google told me)...