# How to store secure login information related to one user of the app in android?

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, sharedpreferences, android-room

I am working on android project using MVVM kotlin and it is an app with payment methods connected to an online API,
my question is:is it secure to save the user login information in a sharedPreference?
and if not, what is the best secure method?

either SharedPreferences or room database

store the user information securely in local storage

Comment: check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925486/android-storing-username-and-password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that neither SharedPreferences or Room db, are good solutions for what you want. I'm assuming you want to store sensible information and not only the user login.

Google have a dedicated guide to [Remember and authenticate users](https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth), that might be what you are looking for.