# Android - Confusion Regarding "Remember me" functionality

Tags: android, preferences

I have read this question:
[How do I implement a 'Remember me' function in an Android Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154438/how-to-implement-remember-me-function-in-login-of-android-activity) ,

I am developing **"Login"** Activity for the first-time,
Where i am also having:

1. two EditText: Username, Password
2. One checkbpx: **Remember me**
3. one Button: Login

If user click on Login Button then Username, Password should be shared among all activity, i know this can be implemented using SharedPreference.

But On "Remember me" checkbox, if user check it once then next-time "Login" Activity should not be appeared, directly 2nd activity should appear, so for that what i should do?

Comment: when the "Remember me" is enabled and a successful login occurs, you simply enable a flag in SharedPref that signifies this Event...along with that, you'll have to save the Username and Password (preferably in some encrypted form) so that the login can be done.

Comment: hi paresh..you got the solution for that?..if so pls share with me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this Scenario, I do that Before Login Activity i have Splash Screen to check whether the Remember Password option enabled or not on the Login Activity.

Splash Screen Also a Activity that has just a well designed image about my App (like loading App screen). Its show for just 3 seconds.

example for Splash Screen in [this link](http://www.anddev.org/simple_splash_screen-t811.html)

Comment: ok i got your idea, it is exact one but what if i dont have splash screen and directly login-activity

Answer (score 1):

In the `onCreate()` method of your Login Activity, before calling `setContentView()` check 'Remember Me' status and if it is true, then call `startActivity()` to open the next Activity. Something like :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  if(isRememberMeChecked()) {
    startActivity(intentForSecondActivity);
    return;
  }

  setContentView(R.layout.act_first);
  ....
  ...
  ..
  .

}
```

Here,`isRememberMeChecked()` is just a simple method which returns a boolean value depending on the Remember Me status, say if I'm using `SharedPreferences` to store the status, then my method will be :

```
private boolean isRememberMeChecked() {
  return sPref.getBoolean(C.REMEMBER_ME, false);
}
```