# How can I save username and password in login application using volley library to sent and request

Tags: android

How can I save username and password in login Application using volley to sent and request .and save setting Remember Me Login

Comment: just use Shared Preference Volley is used for get the data from url

Comment: If you want to save for long duration save it in a DB and if you want it for shorter time you can use SharedPreference

Comment: I mean I want to save username and password so you must login only one  time. i using volley to connect to database

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370293/add-a-remember-me-checkbox) This will help you out.

Comment: Shared preferences is also used for long time store when you uninstall the app that time only the value can be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

When talking about username and password all answer I usually see talk about storing them in `SharedPreferences` and that's totally wrong!!!

What are `SharedPreferences` for? **Preferences**

Is the current user a preference? **NO**

So I always recommend using the [Account Manager System](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html). It's a bit harder to implement but it's the way the system has to implement **user accounts** (which is, BTW, what you have when you use a username + password login)

[Here](http://www.pilanites.com/android-account-manager/) you can find a tutorial about implementing it