# Authentication mechanism in Android?

Tags: android, authentication

I am not basically an android developer. I am a dot net developer, If someone provides me some details on

> How to authenticate and manage the user credentials with android apps.

consider the bellow.

- I have user credentials in SQL database.
- How to authenticate the user
- How to manage the remember password for the later usage.

Can someone give some guidelines ?

Comment: [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) will help you for persistence storage in android

Answer (score 1):

**I have user credentials in SQL database.
How to authenticate the user**

For giving Signin functionality mostly username and password are sent in Base64 String for security. I dont know how they are done on server side but we generally do like this to authenticate user credentials and web service returns response like id of that user. [Try this link](http://webdesignergeeks.com/mobile/android/android-login-authentication-with-remote-db/)

**How to manage the remember password for the later usage.**

This is what you will need for that [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

check this question:

[how to implement Remember me function in login of android Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154438/how-to-implement-remember-me-function-in-login-of-android-activity)

Answer (score 0):

Designing for Security. [Have a look at here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/security.html#UserData)