# Securely Check If User Is Logged In

Tags: java, android

**Question:** What is a secure method of storing and checking if a user is 'Logged in' to an application.

I am building a personal finance application so security is important.

Is storing a key->value pair in SharedPreferences such as loggedin->true secure enough? (My intuition tells me no).

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Much appreciated!

Comment: please look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909999/encrypt-data-in-sharedpreferences

Comment: You're intuition is correct. Saved preferences can easily be accessed to grt passwords, grant access etc. You should maybe try encrypting it first,