# In-app Billing Version 3 API SharedPreferences storage alternative

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, in-app-billing

I'm going through the implementation of Android's [In-app Billing Version 3 API](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html), and came across the following warning in Android's sample code:

```
/*
 * WARNING: on a real application, we recommend you save data in a secure way to
 * prevent tampering. For simplicity in this sample, we simply store the data using a
 * SharedPreferences.
 */
```

I just need to store a simple flag if the user purchases an item, and using an SQLite database seems like overkill. I was just wondering what my alternatives are, seeing as though it looks like Android advises against using SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing data locally on the device is generally considered insecure, and it's not too difficult for a user to access and modify their devices shared preference file. There is no silver bullet here, but the recommended approach is to use your own server and communicate using a [network connection](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#netw).

For your purposes however, the simplest "secure" approach would be to encrypt the SharedPreferences data ([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909999/encrypt-data-in-sharedpreferences)).