# SharedPreferences and security

Tags: php, android, session, sharedpreferences

For my Android app development I am learning SharedPreferences to save user connexion data, and be able to restore each time the use comes on the app.

But I don't understand how to use it: Does the user has access where SharedPreferences is saved? Can he modify it?

For security, do I have to:

- store user id and password (isn't it dangerous to store password???) and try to connect him every time I want to do something (in case the app stays in phone background a long time) by using php $_SESSION?

Or

- store only id, and use it as parameter when I want to do something, like $id instead of $_SESSION['id'], as if user was connect but without sesions variables?

Thank you for answers!

Comment: Ɲḗṽěʀ ęʋěr store a password plaintext!#@!!

Answer (score 0):

> Does the user has access where SharedPreferences is saved? Can he modify it?

Shared preferences are stored in your application's directory which is located in the internal storage. User doesn't have the access to this directory only on the non-rooted devices, but he/she can access it if the device was rooted.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I will encrypt data so it will be more secure.

Answer (score 0):

For doubts about SharedPreferences take a look to the [Android reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

I had this problem some time ago and what I did was a Util class for this purpose.
You can have something like this

```
public class SharedPreferencesUtils {
    private final static String PREF_TOKEN = "TOKEN";
    private final static String PREF_NULL = "";
    private static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(Context context) {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    }
    public static String getToken(Context context) {
        return getSharedPreferences(context).getString(PREF_TOKEN, PREF_NULL);
    }
    public static void setToken(Context context, String token) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(context).edit();
        editor.putString(PREF_TOKEN, token);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

And the use is like this:

```
String token = "this is the token";
SharedPreferencesUtils.setToken(aContext,token);
...
String tokenRetrieved = SharedPreferencesUtils.getToken(aContext);
// tokenRetrieved now is "this is the token"
```

About security, I would recommend to store a token and use it in every communication. That token should have some time of life and have to be regenerated after it

Comment: Thank you, the main issue of Token is that  it has to be regenerate. This is that I don't want to. I want the user is always connect. I will only store sessions variables and use them as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Sharedpreferences is a textfile stored on your phone.
So if you dont manage it wisely, the user could see the data stored in it and do bad things... 
I would propose to encrypt your sharedprefs. 
ref: [encrypt data in SharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909999/encrypt-data-in-sharedpreferences)

Also a possibility is making a Global singleton Class.
You can save the Token & id  in this class for as long the app is running.
if the user would close the app. he would have to relogin because the singleton has expired.

Hope this information was somewhat usefull

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will encrypt data and won't store password! I will store only sessions variables and use them as parameters when I need them