# Detecting a free/paid version of an Android app offline using in-app purchases?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, offline, android-inapp-purchase

I am developing an Android app, and thinking of using in-app purchase to unlock full features of the app.

I want the app to be fully functional even without an active internet connection as well if the user paid, so I don't want to rely on checking the in-app API to check whether they purchased the paid version or not.

boolean userPaid = true;

Could I use shared preferences or internal storage to persist this userPaid data after application close/destroy, and would this be a secure method of storing the data?

Comment: use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to save values(e.g boolean) and also don't forget to set the defaults.

Comment: The In App Billing API works fine while offline as long as you've checked it before while the device is online.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Thanks. Do you have reference for this ? I wanna read

Comment: Thanks for all the input, I will try testing out what @ianhanniballake mentioned to see persistence when I get the chance to publish and test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use simple encrypt to SharedPreferences, Because the mobile rootd are easy to see, folders can be changed.

see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4910308/4797289) for encrypt