# android - having EditText field pre-filled

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an app where I am storing the usernames. Once the user clicks on his username, it goes to the login screen. Can it be done that the username be already inputted in the login screen. , so that the user only has to enter his password. Can we do so with Edittext?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Use SharedPreferences to store previously entered data and setText on the EditText to set the text. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112269/android-keep-username-in-session-until-logout).

Comment: can you please elaborate on this? I am not able to clearly understand from the link you gave me.