# Android textfield and textview from a layout to another

Tags: java, android, textview, textfield

I have two layouts.

One is `activity_main.xml` and the other one is `another_activity.xml`

On `activity_main` I made a login screen. So you have to put your name and press "**log in**".

```
    user_field = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name_field);
    presentation = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    Button signup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_butt);

    signup.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view){
            String danut = user_field.getText().toString();
            setContentView(R.layout.another_activity);
            presentation.append("danu");
        }
   });
```

After you insert your name and press Sign up, it will redirect you to the second layout and prompt your name, **"Welcome, your name"**.

I tried to switch the instructions in **OnClick** ( by setting the content view after append instruction, and still not succes)

> **So the result is:** you put your name, press the signup/login button,
>   you are redirected to the new page and there is only "Welcome, " and
>   nothing.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

```
 EditText user_field;
 TextView presentation;
 String final_text = "";
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button aprinde =(Button)findViewById(R.id.aprinde);
        Button sting = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sting);



        Button signup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_butt);
        user_field = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name_field);
        presentation = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2)

        signup.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                {
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    String danut = user_field.getText().toString();
                    final_text = "Welcome, " + danut;
                    setContentView(R.layout.another_activity);
                    presentation.setText(final_text);
                }
                }
                );
```

Full Code + picture.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3ImY.png

The result on emulator, is the same as the preview ib the picture.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112269/android-keep-username-in-session-until-logout/6112799#6112799

Comment: what's the default text for the presentation textview? (the text which is assigned to it through the xml file)

Comment: So, did you tried to declare the presentation TextView after setcontentview?!!

Comment: I posted the full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use intent, in the first activity you will have the login activity, 
and in the other one there will be the "Welcome..."
pass the data with:

First Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(this, Other_Activity.class);
intent.putExtra("name",danut);
startActivity(intent);
```

Second Activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
```

Comment: He's trying to replace the layout only not the whole Activity.

Comment: MainActivity.java got activity_main.xml  but another_activity.xml don't have a java file.

Comment: how do I create a java file for another_activity.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
String final_text = "";

    signup.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
                    public void onClick(View view)
                    {
                    String danut = user_field.getText().toString();
                    final_text = "Welcome, " + danut;
                    setContentView(R.layout.another_activity);
                    presentation.setText = final_text ;

                    }
                    }
       );
```

**UPDATE:** So far what happened is we tried to get the text from the edit text after changing the layout which takes an empty value and only sets the "Welcome," text.

Comment: Its still the same. It's strange because if I put the textview in the same layout as the login page, it works, but If I try to prompt on another layout, doesn't work.