# Android Application state

Tags: android, authentication, session-state

I am a web developer and starting to learn android development.

I want to authenticate to a custom server which responds with a user object and a JWT (JSON web token) for further authentication.

I know that I need to use intents to show the login page etc.

In a web environment you have access to a session where you can store data in. But I can't find the same principle for an android application.
The state of the current app.
I need this because I want to store the user object and JWT for further requests and to gain access to it in other parts of the application without passing it as a parameter every time.

I guess that I just need to know the sibbling of a session in android to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As a non-web developer I might be wrong, but I see three solutions for this:

1. use a set of constants. For example

   `public class C {
       public final static boolean isAuthenticated = false;
       public final static String userName = "Joe Doe";
   }`
2. use `SharedPreferences` (you can find a lot of examples around) to manually store data of your user. SharedPreferences is a handy way to store global data and if needed save it and load it back if the app is closed, to restore it. Here there is one example: [Android: Keep username in session until logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112269/android-keep-username-in-session-until-logout/6112799#6112799)
3. use a library.

Android's ecosystem is very mature now and there are a lot of libraries that might do your case.
For example the square libraries are really solid and I'm pretty sure that you can find exactly what you need:
https://github.com/square/retrofit

and the lighter (and used inside retrofit)
https://github.com/square/okhttp

Here there is a list of other free libraries that you can insert and that you might explore to find what best is for you on GitHub:
https://github.com/search?q=http&ref=opensearch&l=Java&s=stars

And some other utilities that may come handy:
https://android-arsenal.com/tag/204?sort=created&category=1

With a quick search on GitHub I also found this that explicity talks about sessions: https://github.com/softwaremill/akka-http-session .