# Check if a login and a password is already in Preferences

Tags: android, authentication, passwords, android-preferences

I saw some tutorials for auto login for exemple this one [link](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/preferenceactivity-basics), but when i use the app for the first time, how do i check if the login and password have already been inserted in Preferences Activity ?
What condition should i put ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SharedPreferences sp=PreferenceManager.
               getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
if(sp.contains("Username")){
//login  exists assuming you are saving the username to a preference with the name "Username"
}
```

Comment: btw to be clear: "Username" here is the key name not the value

Comment: ok thank you for that because i didn't get it the first time, and for example in the link i put, that would be : "name" from android:key="name" , and "password" from android:key="password", if i'm right ?

Comment: I suggest you don't save the password in SharedPreference, that would make it really insecure.

Comment: but how can i do it then ? (I'm all about security too)

Comment: there are some suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785973/what-is-the-most-appropriate-way-to-store-user-settings-in-android-application

Comment: here is my json format {"login":[{"status":"error"}]} can anyone help me with login page?