# using sharedpreferences for password - android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

sir, how do access my sharedpreferences file in other class? i want the application to have a default password of 1234, then change it if the user wants to. i've used this code and it works for the first time, but by the time i restart the application, it will revert back to the old password. thanks for help in advance

```
public class ChangePassword extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
EditText enterPassword, newPassword;
public final String filename = "PasswordFile";
String myPassword;
SharedPreferences myFolder;
public static String dataReturned = "";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.changepassword);
    Button save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSavePassword);
    enterPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etCurrentPassword);
    newPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etNewPassword);
    myFolder = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);//a folder
    dataReturned = myFolder.getString("passwordKey", "");
    if(dataReturned.equals(""))
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myFolder.edit();
        editor.putString("passwordKey", "1234"); //newData is new pass, passwordKey is key
        editor.commit();
    }

    save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String stringData = enterPassword.getText().toString().trim();
            dataReturned = myFolder.getString("passwordKey", ""); //key/def message
            //if stored password is equal to entered password
            if(dataReturned.equals(stringData))
            {
                String newData = newPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myFolder.edit();
                editor.putString("passwordKey", newData); //newData is new pass, passwordKey is key
                editor.commit();
                dataReturned  = myFolder.getString("passwordKey", "couldn't load data"); //get file from sharedpref
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Password successfully changed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                enterPassword.setText("");
                newPassword.setText("");
            }
            else 
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Wrong password!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                enterPassword.setText("");
                newPassword.setText("");
            }
        }
    });
}//oncreate()

}
```

here is where i want to use the data saved in sharedpreferences in my other class

```
public void dispatch_button_action(View view){
    final EditText password_input = new EditText(this); // create an text input field
    password_input.setHint("Enter Password"); // put a hint in it
    password_input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD); // change it to password type

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new Builder(this); // create an alert box
    alertDialog.setTitle("Enter Password"); // set the title
    alertDialog.setView(password_input);  // insert the password text field in the alert box
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { // define the 'OK' button
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
             String entered_password = password_input.getText().toString();
             String password = ChangePassword.myFolder.getString("passwordKey", "");
             if(!password.trim().equals(""))
             {
                 testPassAndSendSms(password.trim(), entered_password);
             }
             else
             {
                 testPassAndSendSms(my_password, entered_password);
             }

        } 
    });
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { // define the 'Cancel' button
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        } 
    });
    alertDialog.show(); // show the alert box
}//end dispatch_button
```

Comment: Not really related to your root question: why shared preference values not preserved across activity launches, but why are you storing password in shared pref without any protection? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785973/what-is-the-most-appropriate-way-to-store-user-settings-in-android-application for tips on how to store user passwords on Android

Comment: Here(http://stackoverflow.com/a/20560574/730807) is a extensive discussion on how securely store credentials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are not saving the latest password entered by user in Alertbox so in Another Activity save latest password in SharedPreferences as :

```
 alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
   String entered_password = password_input.getText().toString();
   SharedPreferences myFolder = You_Current_Activitu.this.getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
        String  dataReturned = myFolder.getString("passwordKey", "");
        if(dataReturned.equals(""))
        {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myFolder.edit();
            editor.putString("passwordKey", entered_password); 
            editor.commit();
        }
```

Comment: so the time i entered the password, it will serve as my default password? i actually want the default password as 1234, then the user may choose the change it or not.

Comment: @UsuiTakumi : then just change `editor.putString("passwordKey", entered_password);`to `editor.putString("passwordKey", "1234");`