# Returning users can login with pin code instead of username/password

Tags: android, authentication, firebase, pin-code

I have a pretty basic app that uses Firebase.io for user authorization. I've found some things on how to set up so you can recognize returning users and start them on a different screen as first time users by setting a Boolean value in `getSharedPreferences`. 
I've seen apps that do this, like Discover (a banking app) allows you to set up a 4 digit pin to login with instead of always entering your username and password. 
Does anyone know how this is achieved, where I can look for a tutorial or more info on it?

My first idea was that you would store the pin in `getSharedPreferences` but I couldn't find anything about that and I'm not sure how secure that would be.

Comment: Why can't you use SharedPreferences?

Comment: That was my first idea but I didn't find anything on that being good/bad so I wasn't sure if that was the way to go.

Comment: You can use SharedPreferences for this purpose and the data will persist until and unless you uninstall app

Comment: Ok thank you! I'll give that a shot

Comment: Yes, but don't store your "real" pin, that is, encrypt it in `MD5` for example, `sharedPreferences` can be seen by anyone who has access to mobile...@Shane

Comment: Ok thanks, thats what I was thinking also

Comment: @Aspicas Not if he stores it as private and it can only be accessed by this  application

Comment: @Jas no problem, if you have ur device rooted you can open file, yes on my phone at least... on folder `data/data/com.packageapp.nameapp/`

Comment: Obviously you cannot save any data as private if your phone is rooted

Comment: There is no way to make your data 100% secure. The best you can do is to make it as hard as possible to get.

Comment: yes but so many people have a rooted device, and we must bear in mind, therefore, i said that better way it's store data encrypted. Although in my opinion, `sharedpreferences` should not be to save login data, well... yes, you can use but it's not secure. I agree with @Jas `There is no way to make your data 100% secure.`

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/30149030/4494555. @Shane