# How to secure sharedpreference data in android

Tags: android, cryptography, sharedpreferences

I am developing an android app in android studio. I want to implement a 4-digit passcode feature so that user don't need to enter password every time. User need to enter that 4-digit passcode for login.
But the problem is any hacker can access that passocode in rooted phone. So I want to encrypt it. But the problem is where and how can I securely store the key that will be used at the time of decryption?

Comment: Already answered [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148729/how-to-secure-android-shared-preferences).

Comment: @Adithya I have already seen it. But any person can easily decrypt it.

Comment: Use Asymmetric keys to encrypt .take a look at [this](http://www.androidauthority.com/where-is-the-best-place-to-store-a-password-in-your-android-app-597197/).

Comment: Thank you very much @Adithya
I don't think that there is any approach which we don't need to send key to server in.