# Checking if Shared Preferences is encrypted

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am encrypting the shared preferences with this code:

```java
String masterKeyAlias = MasterKeys.getOrCreate(MasterKeys.AES256_GCM_SPEC);

   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(
       "secret_shared_prefs",
       masterKeyAlias,
       context,
       EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
       EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM
   );

   // use the shared preferences and editor as you normally would
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
```

Taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148729/how-to-secure-android-shared-preferences). 
I would like to know a programmatically method to check if the data is success encrypted. I try the above code to encrypt the shared preferences and don't show me any error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Android Studio, 
start Android Device Monitor, 
go to File Explorer,

and browse "/data/data/< name of your package >/shared_prefs/".

You will find the preferences XML there... and also you can copy it for inspection.
you can see the xml contents (encrypted or decrypted)

Answer (score 2):

You can implement the stetho library to view sharepreferences and many more things, such as databases or http calls, from the web browser.

Too easy

http://facebook.github.io/stetho/