# Is there any proguard rules should use while using EncryptedSharedPreferences?

Tags: android, proguard, androidx, android-jetpack-security

before using **EncryptedSharedPreferences** my app works fine in **release** mode with (minifyEnabled = true), After adding the [security library](https://developer.android.com/topic/security/data) **(version 1.0.0-rc01)** to my application the app crash while opening and if i use (minifyEnabled = false) the app works fine, i think i missing something to add it in **proguard-rules.pro** but i have searched a lot did not found anything.

Comment: this issue is reported too in issuetracker
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154315507

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Looks like something wrong with Tink obfuscation. My current workaround is add this rule to proguard:

```
-keep class com.google.crypto.tink.** { *; }
```

But also keep track of updates of issue [here](http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154315507).

**UPDATE - 06.01.2020**

There is more effective solution (thanks `@jtsalva` to pointing out):

```
-keepclassmembers class * extends com.google.crypto.tink.shaded.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite {
  <fields>;
}
```

**UPDATE - 08.19.2020**

This issue should now fixed in [Version 1.0.0-rc03](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/security#security-crypto-1.0.0-rc03)

Comment: This seems to be the more up to date version `-keepclassmembers class * extends com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite {
  <fields>;
}`

Answer (score 7):

This issue has been answered with a more targeted proguard rule [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154315507#comment26)

```
-keepclassmembers class * extends com.google.crypto.tink.shaded.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite {
    <fields>;
}
```

This saves my app ~0.2MB compared to the currently accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

i try all above . not working for my case.
**this what i do and work perfect:**

```
-keepclassmembers class * extends com.google** {
    <fields>; }
```