# Is there any reliable way to encrypt Shared preference in Android (Min Api 19)

Tags: android, encryption, sharedpreferences

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32250776/secure-way-to-encrypt-decrypt-shared-preference-in-android) and lots of other articles about securing shared preferences
but they all come with a warning that-

> The certificate you use as the password or “secret” in your code is deleted if the lock screen method or PIN/Pattern is changed.

This is the [library](https://github.com/scottyab/secure-preferences/issues/98) people suggesting to use but it has a lot of unresolved issues like if updating to Android Q they are not able to access data.

And EncryptedSharedPreferences can only be used if Min API is 23 (6.0+).

Can someone please suggest if they've found any reliable way to implement encrypt shared preferences?

Comment: You can have an inhouse encryption/decryption logic. When you save a value to shared pref, encrypt it before saving and while you retrieve a value decrypt it before using it. You can write an independent module that takes care of this. All the shared pref related operations should be routed via that module.

Comment: but that encryption logic is not secure, anyone can reverse code my apk and then decode those keys.

Comment: @Ankit Have you found solution? If yes , then please post it.

Comment: @kousalya I'm using both EncryptedSharedPreferences on SharedPreferences according to device version (21+ ESP and below that SP). Also not encrypting data for older version coz thats too slow.

Comment: @Ankit What are you trying to protect against by encrypting SharedPreferences?

Answer (score 4):

A new version of EncryptedSharedPreferences (https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/security/crypto/EncryptedSharedPreferences.html) has been released, supporting API Level 21+! So if you're using version `1.1.0-alpha01` and higher, you can have minSdk version 21.

So this is what you have to put to your `build.gradle`(app): `androidx.security:security-crypto:1.1.0-alpha01`.

Time of typing this, there are newer versions, you can find out more about it here https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/security?authuser=1.

Answer (score -1):

For Preference encryption you can use **EncryptedSharedPreferences** but it provide support from API level 21 (marshmallow).

Below 21 API level you need to encrypt preference data at your end by using AES encryption.
Refer below link
https://github.com/Naibeck/Android-Security

Answer (score -3):

This one is useful for encrypt shared preferences https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/security/crypto/EncryptedSharedPreferences.html

Comment: It requires minSdk version 23

Comment: please check this one https://github.com/marius-bardan/encryptedprefs