# Storing secret key in KeyStore without the ProtectionParameter

Tags: java, android, security, android-keystore

Until now I have used to store my application secrets into the `KeyStore` with the following code:

```
// creating a instance
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

// generating a secret key
SecretKey secretKey = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES").generateKey();

// store the secret key
KeyStore.Entry keyStoreEntry = new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(secretKey);
ProtectionParameter keyPassword = new PasswordProtection("myPassword".toCharArray());
keyStore.setEntry("mySecretKey", keyStoreEntry, keyPassword);
```

According to this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10991545/5086702) in API 14+ the `KeyStore` credential storage is protected by the device unlock password, so there is no need for a `ProtectionParameter`.

But **How** to set a `KeyStore` entry without providing the 3rd parameter?