# PreferenceActivity save as private values?

Tags: android

I don't understand the concect of shared preference in android. Shared prefrerence is accessbile by the ather application on the smartphone?
If i use this class for save preference:

```
    public class ImpostazioniActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.impostazioni);

    } }
```

Anda after in other activity i use:

```
  SharedPreferences preference =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
    if(preference.getString("username","").length() == 0 || preference.getString("password","").length() == 0)
        return  false;
    else
        return  true;
```

It's ok? I'm sure thet the information are accesible only in my application?
Thanks

Comment: You're usage is fine. Any activity that extends from `PreferenceActivity` will use the application's defaultSharedPreferences file.

Comment: Thank you dmon! Other application in the phone can see my preference?

Comment: Nope, but they are just plain text files that you can easily read when plugging the phone in. Any important data should be encrypted as @hovanessyan suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote:

> To get a SharedPreferences object for your application, use one of two
>   methods:
>
> getSharedPreferences() - Use this if you need multiple preferences
>   files identified by name, which you specify with the first parameter.
>
> getPreferences() - Use this if you need only one preferences file for
>   your Activity. Because this will be the only preferences file for your
>   Activity, you don't supply a name

So you should use `getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)` where PREFS_FILENAME is the file you want you application to use and 
`Context.MODE_PRIVATE` is a file creation mode, where the created file can only be accessed by the calling application (or all applications sharing the same user ID).

EDIT: I looked at your code, if you intent to store any sensitive user infromation (like password) you must encrypt it first! Take a look at this [ObscuredSharedPreferences implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785973/what-is-the-most-appropriate-way-to-store-user-settings-in-android-application/6393502#6393502). It will enable you to encrypt/decrypt your data in SharedPreferences.