# Solution for logic behind one time login in a android mobile application

Tags: android

I am working on a android project, which required user's logging only one time until he/she logged out.  All the data are retrieved from web services (Parsing).

Answer (score 1):

After a successful login, save the credentials to SharedPreferences and then use those saved credentials whenever needed.

However if the credentials fail (password change), wipe the SharePreferences and start over again

Comment: don't know how to save the credentials to User Preferences..please provide some link or something please its urgent

Comment: @user3132451 This will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209814/saving-user-information-in-app-settings