# How can I make a button click permanent in the app?

Tags: java, android

Im trying to use a button click to disable a button.

```
    if (currentnumber.equals(maxclicks)) {
        butt.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        currentnumber = currentnumber + 1;
    }
```

I noticed that the effect is not permanent. Once you leave the app, the button comes back and is still enabled. Please help me disable a button after 5 clicks permanently. And I am trying to do this on a button click. Thank you

Comment: have you considered what you mean by permanent? if user uninstalls the app and installs it back, would it be disabled?

Comment: no. what I mean is that I want it to stay at least when the app is closed and opened

Comment: also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209814/saving-user-information-in-app-settings

Comment: but how would I do it on a button click

Comment: what i mean is i want to disable a button on a button click forever until the user deletes it and reinstalls it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be saving that setting somewhere. Then those settings (likely saved in a text file or xml file) should be read into the program & dealt with appropriately.

Every time you restart your program, regardless of what the user interactions were before, its a "clean slate". Thus, you must reference from something (text/xml) that is not cleared on restart.

```
void createFile() throws IOException{

    Path p = Paths.get("myPath.txt");

    Files.createFile(p);


}

void readFromFile() throws Exception {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(""));

    ArrayList<String> myStringArray = new ArrayList<>();

    myStringArray.add(br.readLine());

    br.close();

}
```

Now, you have the strings from the file in your `ArrayList<?> myStringArray`, and you may read through it & decide what to do with the associated information.

There is, however, a better way to do this using the sharedpreferences as linked by other community members.

Comment: i dont know what you mean

Comment: where do i save it

Comment: Hang on buddy, I'll send you what the code would look like

Comment: Use sharedPreferences in Android to save a boolean, to remember if the button needs to set disabled ([sharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23024962/3627279))

Comment: thank you! Ill test it out!

Comment: i dont get this. its just not working for me

Comment: what i mean is i want to disable a button on a button click forever until the user deletes it and reinstalls it

Comment: Right. I think your best option here would be to use the sharedPreferences thread on here. Hopefully that reading will help you David :)

Comment: i used shared preference and it worked

Comment: but i accidently deleted the file with some other files

Comment: so i tried again and it doesnt work

Comment: whenever i hit back on the phone, the button resets