# how to use shared preference concept in loginpage in android

Tags: android

when I give username and password on clicking login button means login will get successfully.
when I give username and password on clicking check box and after if I login successfully and I close the application now if I again open the application username and password has to be their in textboxes. now I directly click on login button and it has to be login success fully.

I try this code

```
public class Login extends Activity {
    CheckBox check;

    private static final String UPDATE_URL = "http://202.62.91.45/NewCozyDine/login1.php3";
    public ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private EditText UserEditText;
    private EditText PassEditText;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        UserEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        PassEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        check=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.okbutton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int usersize = UserEditText.getText().length();
                int passsize = PassEditText.getText().length();
                if(usersize > 0 && passsize > 0) {
                    progressDialog.show();
                    String user = UserEditText.getText().toString();
                    String pass = PassEditText.getText().toString();
                    doLogin(user, pass);
                } else createDialog("Error","Please enter Username and Password");
            }
        });
```

I wrote for login button for xml parser(Validating from server database). how can wrote for check box for remember

Comment: Take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html. Use SharedPreferences to store your credentials and checkbox state and retrieve on next invocation.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
 public SharedPreferences prefs;
 public String prefName = "MyPref";
 private static final String REMEMBER = "remember_me";
 public static final String Password = "volume_range";
 public static final String User_Name = "my_alarmstate";
 prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);      
 remember_state  = prefs.getBoolean(REMEMBER, false);   
 remember_chebox.setChecked(remember_state);
 if(remember_state == true) {

            uname_et.setText(prefs.getString(User_Name, null));
            password_et.setText(prefs.getString(Password, null));
        }

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();


                editor.putString(User_Name, entered_name);
                editor.putString(Password, entered_password);   
                editor.putBoolean(REMEMBER, remember_state);
                editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just identify that on Checkbox Selected. on its Listner you will have to use SharedPreference, this will saves your data in the Application.

```
CheckBox savepass;
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
private static final String PREF_USERNAME = "username";
private static final String PREF_PASSWORD = "password";
private static final String PREF_STATUS = "status";

savepass = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.remeber);
savepass.setChecked(false);
```

//On Sign in Button write this code. This code is used for Saving in SharedPreference

```
if (savepass.isChecked()) {
                getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
                        .putString(PREF_USERNAME, uid.getText().toString())
                        .putString(PREF_PASSWORD, pwd.getText().toString())
                        .putString(PREF_STATUS, "true").commit();
                /*
                 * Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                 * "Saved Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 */
            }else {
                getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
                        .putString(PREF_USERNAME, "").putString(
                                PREF_PASSWORD, "").putString(PREF_STATUS,
                                "").commit();
//this else part is if user has already been checked and saved in application, then name of the user will be displayed on username and password edittextbox.
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (successful login and remember-me checkbox is marked...) {
    SharedPreferences SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor = SP.edit();
    spEditor.putString("username"),userName);
    spEditor.putString("password",password);
    spEditor.commit();
```

then on onCreate you just check if it already exist and present it if it does.

```
SharedPreferences SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    userName = SP.getString("username", "none");
if (!userName.equal("none"))
    editText.setText(userName);
....
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are About to Use `SharedPreferences` in your Application .I like you to look in this one SO link for `SharedPreferences`.

Go here for [Saving Data in SharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785973/what-is-the-most-appropriate-way-to-store-user-settings-in-android-application).I would like you to use encrypting  for Password.

For a guide to using AES encryption in Android Refer this

[http://developer.motorola.com](http://developer.motorola.com/docs/using_the_advanced_encryption_standard_in_android/)