# user credentials on android

Tags: android, mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the most appropriate way to store user settings in Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785973/what-is-the-most-appropriate-way-to-store-user-settings-in-android-application)

For applications need login info (usr/pwd), users typically have to type in the info once. So where do applications store the sensitive credential information, and what encryption is used?

Comment: This is a great question, but it has been asked a lot. Theres isn't an easy solution. Check the link I pasted above

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! So how can I close this question? In the past, I simply deleted.

Comment: Is the delete option not available? If not i'll flag it and ask a moderator to close it.