# Using a custom subclass of SharedPreferences with PreferenceActivity or PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I'm using a custom subclass of SharedPreferences to encrypt my saved settings in the app, similar to what's being done in the second response here: [What is the most appropriate way to store user settings in Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785973/what-is-the-most-appropriate-way-to-store-user-settings-in-android-application)

The number of preferences I have to save is growing. Before I was just using a custom view to update these preferences but that is going to become cumbersome and I want to use PreferenceActivity or PreferenceFragment instead. Problem is, it does not seem that there is a way to have either of those classes access my data using my subclass, meaning that the data it pulls from the default preferences file is going to be gibberish as it wasn't decrypted.

I've found that some people have created custom implementations of Preference that encrypt the data there, but I'd prefer not to do that as the data is already being encrypted/decrypted in my SharedPreferences subclass and I'd like to keep it that way. I've also been looking over the source code of PreferenceActivity and PreferenceManager and I'm not sure the best way to approach this.

Has anyone else had any luck accomplishing something like this and have any suggestions as to where I might start?

Comment: I've been looking at doing this in support of [my own encrypted preferences project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-prefs). The only solution I have figured out would require basically forking and cloning much of the preference UI system. At minimum, you'd have to fork `PreferenceFragment` (and `PreferenceActivity` if you are supporting pre-HC devices), plus all the resources they directly refer to. It is possible that's "all" that is needed, but I can't rule out needing to fork and clone yet more code.

Comment: @JayLamont Sorry to bother. Could you, please, provide link to custom implementations of Preference that encrypt the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think by keeping your encryption in the SharedPrefs subclass that you already have, you limit the modularity and the separation of concerns.

So I would suggest reconsidering sub-classing the preference classes themselves (such as CheckBoxPreference) and perform your calculation there.

Ideally you could also use some type of composition or a static utility so that while you might have to subclass each type of preference you use, you can use a single place to perform the encryption/decryption calculations.  This would also allow you more flexibility in the future if you need to encrypt or decrypt some other data or if the API changes.

For sub-classing maybe you could do this:

So for example:

```
class ListPreferenceCrypt extends ListPreference
{
    ListPreferenceCrypt (Context context, AttributeSet attrs)   {
        super ( context, attrs );
    }
    ListPreferenceCrypt (Context context)   {
        super ( context );
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue( String value )
    {
        //encrypt value
        String encryptedVal = MyCryptUtil.encrypt(value);
        super.setValue ( encryptedVal );
    }

    @Override
    public String getValue( String key )
    {
        //decrypt value
        String decryptedValue = MyCryptUtil.decrypt(super.getValue ( key ));
        return decryptedValue;
    }

}
```

***NOTE** the above is psuedo-code, there would be different methods to override*

And your XML might look like this:

```
<PreferenceScreen
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory
            android:title="@string/inline_preferences">

        <com.example.myprefs.ListPreferenceCrypt
                android:key="listcrypt_preference"
                android:title="@string/title_listcrypt_preference"
                android:summary="@string/summary_listcrypt_preference" />

    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

**EDIT**

*Caveats/Decompiling*

As I thought about this more, I realized one of the caveats is that this method is not particularly difficult to bypass when decompiling an APK.  This does give the full class names of overriden classes in the layouts (though that can be avoided by not using XML)

However, I don't think this is significantly less secure than sub-classing `SharedPreferences`.  That too, is susceptible to decompiling.  Ultimately, if you want stronger security, you should consider alternative storage methods. Perhaps OAuth or the AccountManager as suggested in your linked post.

Comment: The OP wrote: "I've found that some people have created custom implementations of Preference that encrypt the data there, but I'd prefer not to do that as the data is already being encrypted/decrypted in my SharedPreferences subclass and I'd like to keep it that way."

Comment: Right, but my suggestion (as I said in my post) is to reconsider that stance :)

Comment: It's looking more and more like this will be the best way to approach it, and my SharedPreferences implementation shouldn't be the be-all-end-all gateway for accessing the data.

Thanks for the suggestion!!

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

- Store a byte[16] in a .SO. If you do not use a .SO then make one just for that purpose.
- Use that byte array to crypt a new byte[16] then Base64 encode the result. Hardcode that in your class file.

Now that you've setup the keys let me explain:

Yes, potentially one could peek into the .SO and find the byte array ergo your key. But with the cyphered key2 being base64 encoded, he would need to decode it and reverse the encryption with the said key to extract key2 bytes. So far this only involves dissassembling the app.

- When you want to store encrypted data, first do a AES pass with key1, then a AES/CBC/Padding5 pass with Key2 and an IV*
- You can safely Base64 encode the IV and save it like that in your /data/data folder if you'd like to change the IV every time a new password is stored.

With these two steps disassembling the app is no longer the only thing required, as it's now required to also take control of your runtime to get to the crypted data. Which you have to say is pretty sufficient for a stored password.

Then you could simply store that into SharedPreferences :) That way if your SharedPreferences get compromised, the data is still locked away. I don't think subclassing it is really the right approach but since you already wrote your class - oh well.

Here's some code to further illustrate what I mean

```
//use to encrypt key
public static byte[] encryptA(byte[] value) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException
{
    SecretKeySpec sks = getSecretKeySpec(true);
    System.err.println("encrypt():\t" + sks.toString());
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sks, cipher.getParameters());
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value);
    return encrypted;
}

//use to encrypt data
public static byte[] encrypt2(byte[] value) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException
{
    SecretKeySpec key1 = getSecretKeySpec(true);
    System.err.println("encrypt():\t" + key1.toString());
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key1, cipher.getParameters());
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value);

    SecretKeySpec key2 = getSecretKeySpec(false);
    System.err.println("encrypt():\t" + key2.toString());
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key2, new IvParameterSpec(getIV()));
    byte[] encrypted2 = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);

    return encrypted2;//Base64Coder.encode(encrypted2);
}
//use to decrypt data
public static byte[] decrypt2(byte[] message, boolean A) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException
{
    SecretKeySpec key1 = getSecretKeySpec(false);
    System.err.println("decrypt():\t" + key1.toString());
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key1, new IvParameterSpec(getIV()));
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(message);

    SecretKeySpec key2 = getSecretKeySpec(true);
    System.err.println("decrypt():\t" + key2.toString());
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key2);
    byte[] decrypted2 = cipher.doFinal(decrypted);

    return decrypted2;
}

    //use to decrypt key
public static byte[] decryptKey(String message, byte[] key) throws GeneralSecurityException
{
    SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(key, ALGORITHM);
    System.err.println("decryptKey()");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks);
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(Base64Coder.decode(message));
    return decrypted;
}

//method for fetching keys
private static SecretKeySpec getSecretKeySpec(boolean fromSO) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, GeneralSecurityException
{
    return new SecretKeySpec(fromSO ? getKeyBytesFromSO() : getKeyBytesFromAssets(), "AES");
}
```

What do you think?

I realize it might be off topic since you're asking about using your own SharedPreferences but I'm giving you a working solution to the problem of storing sensitive data :)

Comment: "What do you think?" -- we already know how to store data in encrypted `SharedPreferences`. We do not know how to tie this into the standard `PreferenceScreen` UI. I fail to see how your solution addresses this.

Comment: ... i guess i'll delete it if it turns out useless.

Comment: It's not useless, but it does not answer the question, either.

Comment: Personally I'd store crypted data in the regular SharedPreferences, but if you want to go the other way around - here's a fall-back plan you can use :) I'm interested in how this develops too.