# can someone explain me how SharedPreferences works in Android in a very detailed yet easy understanding?

Tags: android, authentication, sharedpreferences

I'm novice in Android development and now I'd really like to learn Shared Preferences. I've googled it so many times and I don't think I quite mastered it.

I believe this Shared Preferences will help me to store username and a password on my login screen activity. Thanks you!

Comment: Be more specific. What don't you understand?

Comment: @Anggrian It's best explained here with an example. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I made some videos about this as an audition for a job. They helped me get the job, and they're still available on Vimeo, so hopefully they can help you out.

Part 1: [Saving Data](http://vimeo.com/38073839)

Part 2: [Retrieving Data](http://vimeo.com/38080004)

Also, for what it's worth, be careful storing usernames and passwords in SharedPreferences. You can do it there, but read up on the risks in this other SO question: [What is the most appropriate way to store user settings in Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785973/what-is-the-most-appropriate-way-to-store-user-settings-in-android-application)

Comment: Thanks Ben!  I watched your videos and it made me remember where I've seen your face before ;) !  Thanks for everything!

Comment: Hehe - I'm glad these are still useful! We cover them in two courses at Treehouse now.

Answer (score 5):

For android, there are primarly three basic ways of persisting data:

- shared preferences to save small chunks of data
- tradition file systems
- a relational database management system through the support of SQLite databases

SharedPreferences object help you save simple application data as a name/value pairs - you specify a name for the data you want to save, and then both it and its value will be saved automatically to an XML file for you. To save a data in sharedPreferences file:

1. Obtain an instance of sharedPreferences file:
   SharedPreferences appPrefs = getSharedPreferences( or fileName, MODE_PRIVATE);
2. Create SharedPreferences.Editor object
3. To put for example a String value into SharedPreferences object use putString() method.
4. To save the changes to the preferences file, use the commit() method

That will look like this:

```
// obtain an instance of the SharedPreferences class
preferences = getSharedPreferences(prefFileName, MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = preferences.edit();

// save username String
editor.putString("username", student).commit();
```

To retrieve it use getString() method:

```
preferences.getString(username, null) where null is a default value that will be returned if username key is not found in the file.
```