# Android Login box on main activity

Tags: java, android, authentication

First things first, I'm a novice in Android and apologize for anything unreasonable.

What I'm trying to do here is to display Main activity and show an AlertDialog, asking for short password (full username and password will be saved in Preferences). I need to find a way to exit the application if the passcode doesn't match, otherwise, load main activity.

Here is my code so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
Button  screening;
Button  screeningLog;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    resetPreferences ();
    // Set theme
    setTheme (App.getTheme ());
    setContentView (R.layout.main);
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
    createControlsAndListeners ();

    if (!App.isLoggedIn ())
    {
        final LinearLayout view = new LinearLayout (this);
        final TextView passcodeText = new TextView (this);
        final EditText passcode = new EditText (this);

        passcodeText.setText (R.string.passcode);
        passcode.setHint (R.string.passcode_hint);
        passcode.setInputType (InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);

        view.setOrientation (LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        view.addView (passcodeText);
        view.addView (passcode);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder (this);
        builder.setTitle ("Enter Passcode.");
        builder.setView (view);
        builder.setPositiveButton (R.string.login, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener ()
        {
            public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
            {
                if (App.get (passcode).equals (App.getPassword ().substring (0, 4)))
                {
                    App.setLoggedIn (true);
                    dialog.dismiss ();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText (MainActivity.this, Error.get (Error.AUTHENTICATION),
                            App.getDelay ());
                    toast.show ();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show ();
    }
}

public void resetPreferences ()
{
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues (this, R.xml.preferences, false);
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences (this);
    App.setServer (preferences.getString ("server", ""));
    App.setUsername (preferences.getString ("username", ""));
    App.setPassword (preferences.getString ("password", ""));
    App.setNightMode (preferences.getBoolean ("night_mode", false));
    App.setDelay (Integer.parseInt (preferences.getString ("delay", "30000")));
}

private void createControlsAndListeners ()
{
    screening = (Button) findViewById (R.main_id.screeningButton);
    screening.setOnClickListener (this);
    screeningLog = (Button) findViewById (R.main_id.screeningLogButton);
    screening.setOnClickListener (this);
}
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error??? And you can try and add one more java class in between main activity and splashscreen... which will be login screen ..or you want login to be displayed in alert dialog only???

Comment: Rather than close the App, it might make a slightly better UX if you allowed the user the option of entering a password again/showing an error, rather than terminate the application without feedback - this would also account for a mistake made, instead of forced entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it might help you. You can use the intent for this.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder (this);
builder.setTitle ("Enter Passcode.");
builder.setView (view);
builder.setPositiveButton (R.string.login, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener ()
{
    public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
    {
        if (App.get (passcode).equals (App.getPassword ().substring (0, 4)))
        {
            App.setLoggedIn (true);
            dialog.dismiss ();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText (MainActivity.this, Error.get (Error.AUTHENTICATION),App.getDelay ());
            toast.show ();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
});
builder.show ();
```

**Or 
If this is your first activity in app then call `finish()` method in else condition.**

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder (this);
    builder.setTitle ("Enter Passcode.");
    builder.setView (view);
    builder.setPositiveButton (R.string.login, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener ()
    {
        public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
        {
            if (App.get (passcode).equals (App.getPassword ().substring (0, 4)))
            {
                App.setLoggedIn (true);
                dialog.dismiss ();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText (MainActivity.this, Error.get (Error.AUTHENTICATION),App.getDelay ());
                toast.show ();
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show ();
```

Comment: Thanks! It helped, this is the first activity.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in Android there really isn't an "exit application". But if you really want to provide that kind of functionality I guess you may direct the user to the home screen, through an Intent (see [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_HOME)).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call finish() on your activity to close it.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to exit you can use finish();

About shared preferences for storing password, I suggest you read this post:
[What is the most appropriate way to store user settings in Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785973/what-is-the-most-appropriate-way-to-store-user-settings-in-android-application)

Comment: Thanks but in my case, passwords aren't really that critical.