# Entering login first time vs return user, storing in app memory?

Tags: android, authentication

So I'm writing an Android app and basically every time you start it up, it prompts you to enter a PIN before allowing you to launch the app.

Two things I'm kind of having problems with is:

1. How do I create a first time login vs a returning user for the app? The way I figured is that I have a variable called PIN and if its equal to null, I launch the first time login, wherein you can set the PIN to basically not null. This however leads to my second bigger problem.
2. How do I create variables that remain defined even when the app is closed? At first I thought just define those variables globally, but that doesn't seem to be it at all. I realize there are probably sources for this, but I've tried searching and I'm not sure what to type into Google. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Please always ensure you use the tagging system. Not every question on [so] is about Android so you should tag your question with the language you're using...

Comment: Have you looked into SQLite?

Answer (score 2):

You can use shared preferences to store your variables.
Take a look at this article. It might be usefull to you: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

Also take a look at this topic in SO:
[How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

After the user enter the PIN for the first time, save it in a shared preference. Then in the main activity you can retrieve the preference and if it is not set, redirect to the login activity.

Comment: Glad I could help. If my answer has helpull please accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `SharedPreferences` for that. See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `shared preferences` for this purpose.

if the user has logged in first time you need to create preferences and store the detail like username in them.

they will have the values stored even when you close your app.

The shared preferences will be stored in phone so keep in mind not to store critical information like password in them.

i think this might help you understanding [check this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785973/what-is-the-most-appropriate-way-to-store-user-settings-in-android-application)