# add cookies in django

Tags: django, cookies, addition

I want to set cookies in order to save to refresh token. I've triyed using set_cookies() function with a HttpResponse object but there's no cookies get in Postman. I've triyed also with a Response object but I've get an **"AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'set_cookie' "**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fQhv.png)

[Response in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fQhv.png)
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvMBQ.png)

Comment: Maybe add the code how you tried it with an `HttpResponse`...

Comment: the code was captured in Pic :  ** "Code" ** and the server response in ** " Response in Postman" **

Comment: Does this answer your question? [saving authentication token in cookie (Django Rest Framework + React)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51143285/saving-authentication-token-in-cookie-django-rest-framework-react)