# authenticate between android and backend server

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I really want to know authentication about android..
I want to know about 2 case authentication (just android application login, android application login and web application login)

1. just android application
   When i signed in sns like facebook or twitter, I got token and send it to server.
2. app and web

   - What if already have ID with sns in web application, what should i do?
   - Application sign in and got token. And next, send token to server and authenticate in server?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of applications use token based authentication, where server is separated from the whole application, which e.g. allows to use one restful api for many services like mobile app and web app.

Basically it works this way, that first user sends his login and password through secured connection to your server, and then the server generates a token that allows user to get certain data from that server. Those tokens are made to expire after some time (for security reasons). You can read more about [token based authentication](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-ins-and-outs-of-token-based-authentication), tokens, [refresh tokens](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/refresh-token), [json web token](https://jwt.io/introduction/) and similar things.

Here you have similar question on this topic, on stack overflow: 
[How do popular apps authenticate user requests from their mobile app to their server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19799416/how-do-popular-apps-authenticate-user-requests-from-their-mobile-app-to-their-se)

And here you have an overview of other types of authentication: 
https://blog.risingstack.com/web-authentication-methods-explained/