# Easy way to save values through many appstarts?

Tags: android, defaults

is there a way to save values through various starts of an app?
I need to save some statistics (records of a game).
In objective-c I used UserDefaults, what's it in Java?
If possible I'd like to take a simple way (one line of code).

Comment: possible solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785973/what-is-the-most-appropriate-way-to-store-user-settings-in-android-application?lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> one line of code

No, that's not going to happen. But if you just have simple data and not much of it then you can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

There is a good, basic example of using `SharedPreferences` [here in the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

But if you are going to be storing a lot of data for a game then you probably want to implement an [SQLite DB](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)

[See Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) for what will work best for you.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to use a DB for the heavy data. Just for a simple int-value the SharedPreferences will work.