# Android: OAuth2 - How do I implement remember me functionality?

Tags: android, security, oauth, oauth-2.0

A bit of background:

1. User enters credentials on every app launch instance.
2. These credentials are sent as a part of the POST body (we encrypt them with a key using AES and put in the post body) to server and we get back a token which is some encoded string from the server.
3. This token will authorize our app to make requests.

Now I would like you readers to focus on the fact that **we need user credentials to get an authorization token in the first place.**

4. **Token expires in 12 hours** and all the subsequent requests are unauthorized and we are forced to kick the user out of the app to relogin again and get a new token which is good for another 12 hrs. I KNOW ITS A BAD EXPERIENCE.

Now we are required to implement a remember me functionality. I am NOT AT ALL COMFORTABLE using shared preferences (even with encryption, a serious hacker might get to the key in this case). What should I do ? I just came to know that the token web service is an oAuth2. Im a novice still looking at articles about oAuth2 and I saw where people have huge discussions about SharedPrefs and AccountManager api. But I saw this one [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/786588/2423312) by Reto Meier. He mentions that server should use oAuth. My question is given my scenario, what is the most secure way to do this and how can I use anything with oAuth to implement the remeber me functionality. Any kind of "clear" examples/clear explanantion would be a great help. Looking forward for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

This is solely my opinion and could be less than 100% correct.

I am currently struggling with this but some of the things I know that could result are:

- Store passwords in server's database using a derivation function
  along with hash + salt, being the salt unique to each user;
- Implement oAuth by sending the username and password (hashed or plain
  text doesn't matter) via HTTPS to the server one single time, he
  returns a token with a given expiration time. For example Dropbox
  oAuth token has a huge validation, doesn't mean it is less safe. You 
  just have to invalidate the token if the user is compromised;
- Store the token in SharedPreferences in the device and use it as the 
  remember me.

Comment: Thanks for response. I will mark your answer with some more research :). May I know, only if its ok for you, what issues are you struggling with ?